# cocoa pods Dependency management

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, afnetworking, cocoapods

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `SDWebImage (= 3.7)` required by `DZNPhotoPickerController/Core (1.6.0)`
- `AFNetworking (~> 3.0)` required by `Podfile`
- `AFNetworking (~> 1.3.3)` required by `DZNPhotoPickerController (1.0.2)`

**PodFile**

```
pod 'DZNPhotoPickerController'
pod 'ZXingObjC', '~> 3.0'
pod 'vfrReader','~>2.8.6'
pod 'Mantle'
pod 'PPSSignatureView'
pod 'AFNetworking','~>3.0'
pod 'JNKeychain'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'ZipArchive'
```

I want to update AFNetworking.

**Help me to solve this**

Answer (score 2):

To fix this you might need to

> Fork the DZNPhotoPickerController repo and modify the dependency in
>   the Pod spec and then use your forked repo's git location in the pod
>   file. Not a great solution for the long term but works.

For instance, The Pod spec [here](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNPhotoPickerController/blob/master/DZNPhotoPickerController.podspec) should have the **line#33** which is

```
ss.dependency 'AFNetworking'
```

should be changed to

```
ss.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
```

in your forked repo.

Then use in your Pod file as below

```
pod 'DZNPhotoPickerController', :git => 'https://github.com/yourUsername/DZNPhotoPickerController.git'
```

Your forked repo is not guaranteed to work out of the box if the project relies on legacy dependency code, if any. In this particular case, if it uses any methods of AFNetworking that is removed in 3.0 it will not work.

Comment: I forked here https://github.com/Piyush08/DZNPhotoPickerController

but it shows me error for 
when I used pod 'MyDZNPhotoController', :git => 'https://github.com/Piyush08/DZNPhotoPickerController'

Comment: Since your repository name is `DZNPhotoPickerController `, use it as `DZNPhotoPickerController', :git => 'https://github.com/Piyush08/DZNPhotoPickerController'`

Answer (score 0):

To update a single AFNetworking pod,

```
pod update AFNetworking
```

with above code, cocoapods will find a latest updated pod version and update your pod.

To update your all pods you can use

```
pod update
```

this will update your all the pods.

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like 'DZNPhotoPickerController' has dependancy of  `ss.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6.0'` so when you are trying to update AFNetworking to version 3.0 it shows the wrong version error.

If you didn't check it recently the 'DZNPhotoPickerController' has also updated it's podspec to make AFNetworking to 3.0 so you should try `pod update` now it may fix your issue as both dependancy needs the same version

If the above and the fork 'DZNPhotoPickerController' in to newer one didn't work

- Please remove the 'DZNPhotoPickerController' from the cocoapods
- update the cocoapods by `pod update`
- if it's successful add
  the 'DZNPhotoPickerController' dependancy again in the cocoapods and
  install that again it may solve your problem